# Extracting eigenvalues of a circulant matrix using discrete Fourier matrix

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, convolution

The eigenvalues of a circulant matrix $C$ can be extracted as $$
\Lambda=F^{-1} C F
$$

where the $F$ matrix is a discrete Fourier transform matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Since $F^{-1}F$=$FF^{-1}=I$, is it possible to write  $$
\Lambda=FC F^{-1} 
?$$

For example, if our circulant matrix were:

$$C=\begin{pmatrix} 2& -1& 0& 0& 0& 0& -1\\ -1& 2& -1& 0& 0& 0& 0&\\ 0& -1& 2& -1& 0& 0& 0\\ 0& 0& -1& 2& -1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& -1& 2& -1& 0\\ 0& 0& 0& 0& -1& 2& -1\\ -1& 0& 0& 0& 0& -1& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

There is no practical difference in the numerical values of the eigenvalues from those two approaches, i.e., whether the position of the inverse Fourier matrix is first or the last, it does not seem to matter here.

Is there a mathematical basis for this observation and is this property true for all circulants? $C$ happens to be a symmetric matrix. I am looking for a reference to explain this.

I am not a mathematician, my interest is in signal deconvolution problems for chemistry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrete Fourier transform matrix $F$ is special because it squares to a permutation matrix,$^\ast$ $F^2=P$ with $P^2=I$. I insert $I=F^2 P=P F^{-2}$,
$$F^{-1}\Lambda F= F^{-1}(F^2 P) \Lambda (P F^{-2})F=F(P\Lambda P)F^{-1}.$$
So you see that you can either write $\Lambda=FCF^{-1}$ or $\Lambda'=F^{-1}CF$, the difference is simply that $\Lambda'=P\Lambda P$ is a reordering of the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

---

$^{\ast}$ See, for example, the [DFT wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)

---

In special case of the matrix in the OP, the permutation matrix is

$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$

which commutes with the circulant matrix $C$. Hence in this case $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$ are the same.

Comment: That is very interesting. Could you expand the middle step, i.e., we left and right multiplied $F^{-1}CF$ by $I$ to get $IF^{-1}CFI$ ? What is meaning of $F^{-2}$? Thanks.

Comment: I worked it out a bit more; with $F^{-2}$ mean the inverse of $F$ squared.

Comment: Thank you, In this very special case, $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda^{'}$ are the same because we are dealing with identity matrices. Do you recall a book which will have this discussion?

Comment: For the $C$ shown there, I double checked, the difference in eigenvalue matrices is {0.00000000000000 + 0.00000000000000i
1.11022302462516e-16 + 3.96081576336899e-18i
0.00000000000000 - 3.31940775686931e-17i
0.00000000000000 + 3.52227426653176e-17i
0.00000000000000 - 3.52227426653176e-17i
0.00000000000000 + 3.31940775686931e-17i
1.11022302462516e-16 - 3.96081576336899e-18i}

Comment: Practically no difference. Why is this the case, whereas you expect some re-ordering?

Comment: in this special case the circulant matrix commutes with the permutation matrix, so the reordering has no effect; this is possible because $C$ has only four distinct eigenvalues, in general all eigenvalues of the circulant matrix will be distinct.